# autoware auto avp demo: JoyStick controling lgsvl ego car failed to get reversed

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Description

According to lgsvl docs, I changed the ros2bridge from 'websocker-bridge' to 'ros2-lgsvl-bridge' to get better performance.

But I found that the ego car cannot be reversed control through vehicle interface node using the joy node

My joystick is logitech F310, the same as yours.

I want to know if the problem is in the simulator or the vehicle interface.

thanks!

#### How to Reproduce

##### Environment

- ubuntu20.04
- lgsvl 2020.06
- ros2-lgsvl-bridge(note web-socket-bridge)
- autoware.auto avp 1.0.0 code

the launch files are below
[zs_joy.launch.py](/uploads/7a3565a2a08e839a11a424fccc591e1c/zs_joy.launch.py)

[zs_lgsvl.launch.py](/uploads/2217d0cfce374154beb1a772c6202802/zs_lgsvl.launch.py)

[zs_localization.launch.py](/uploads/19de4dc3df028afd0885d46a8fa7201c/zs_localization.launch.py)

1. launch lgsvl, and select autonomousstuff environment according to avp demo
2. launch lgsvl bridge, see `zs_lgsvl.launch.py`
3. launch localization and perception stack, localizing the car through rviz2, see`zs_localization.launch.py`
4. launch joy stack, see `zs_joy.launch.py`, changing the joy control mode from `raw` to `basic`
5. try to control ego car through joy node, touch `Y` button to get the reversed gear, and let car drive

#### Current Behavior

the ego car drive forward, not backward.

[image]

#### Expected behavior

the ego car drive backward.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374880/autoware-auto-avp-demo:-joystick-controling-lgsvl-ego-car-failed-to-get-reversed./) by [zhensheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/47322/zhensheng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2021-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug tracked with https://github.com/lgsvl/simulator/issues/1303

---

Originally posted by [zhensheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/47322/zhensheng/) with karma: 33 on 2021-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0